# Laravel 5.5 Log in user using event listener

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, laravel-5.5

So, I'm trying to log in a user on Laravel 5.5 using SSO. I'm using a library and it works fine, data come back correctly. However when on Listener I try to Auth::login or any Session data, it's not saved. Sessions works fine from any other point of the app, but not in Listener Events.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use \Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class AuthListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Saml2LoginEvent $event)
    {
        $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
        // your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks
        $user = $event->getSaml2User();
        $attributes = $user->getAttributes();

        $id = $attributes['id'];
        $laravelUser = User::where('id', $id)->first();

        \Session::push('name', 'test');
        Auth::login($laravelUser, true);

    }
}
```

Now, at the **Auth::login($laravelUser, true)** the user is logged in correctly, I did check. But as soon as the page refresh sending to the final URL the session is gone.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect the problem is that you're not actually returning a response with a session cookie. Therefore, if you check immediately after logging the user in (on the next line), you'll find that the user has been authenticated for _this_ request, but on subsequent requests, they're not being re-associated with their previous session.

Comment: And FYI, you can use the `find` method to lookup users by `id`. E.g. `$laravelUser = User::find($id);`

Comment: @fubar I know. I’m not really using Id field there. I was just simplify the code. I think that the issue is on the middleware for the routes (they are done from a vendor). I’ll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact problem in Laravel 5.5. It seems that you are missing the **routesMiddleware** setting in **saml2_settings.php** file. The description says you need a group which includes **StartSession**, so you may want to put **'web'** there, which has it included by default, as seen in Kernel.php